# How to use GNOME Terminal instead of XTerm here?

Tags: vim, argument-passing, xterm, gnome-terminal

I have the following variable defined in `~/.vimrc`. This works well with XTerm but I can't get it working with GNOME Terminal. Please help.

```
let g:slimv_client = 'python /home/dumrat/.vim/ftplugin/slimv.py -r "xterm -e sbcl --core /home/dumrat/.sbcl/sbcl.core -s"'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `-e` makes XTerm run the command specified by all of the remaining
command line arguments following `-e`.  Consequently, `xterm -e sbcl --core
/home/dumrat/.sbcl/sbcl.core -s` opens an XTerm instance running `sbcl --core
/home/dumrat/.sbcl/sbcl.core -s` command.

GNOME Terminal has the option `-x` with the same meaning that `-e` has for
XTerm.<sup>1</sup>  Thus, change the configuration file, as follows.

```
let g:slimv_client = 'python /home/dumrat/.vim/ftplugin/slimv.py -r "gnome-terminal -x sbcl --core /home/dumrat/.sbcl/sbcl.core -s"'
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  Note that `-e` has somewhat different behavior in GNOME
Terminal—the whole command is expected to be in the next argument, while `-x`
assumes that everything to the end is the command to run.